# Verification for basis and span for a function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering if someone could check my work and reasoning for the following question.

> Define functions $f_1,f_2,f_3 \in F$ by
> $$f_1(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1},f_2(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+2},f_3(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+3}$$ a) Show that the function $g \in F$ defined by:
> $$f_1(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+2)(x^2+3)}$$
> is in the space $W=\text{Span}\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ and express $g$ as a linear combination of $f_1,f_2,f_3$.

This is essentially partial fraction decomposition, although I could also use linear combinations to do this. Either way, I get:

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}-\frac{1}{x^2+2}+\frac{1}{2(x^2+3)}$$

So I've shown that $g(x)$ is a linear combination of $f_1(x)$,$f_2(x)$ and $f_3(x)$.

This might seem like a silly question but does that show that $g(x)$ is in the span of $f_1,f_2,f_3$? I feel like I haven't actually shown that or I am misunderstanding the definition of span. To me, span is the set of all possible linear combinations and I'm not sure if what I've done proves that $g$ is in the span of $f_1,f_2,f_3$.

> b)Show that $B=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is a linearly independent set.

This is trivial. I know it is. If I set my coefficients, gather like terms and solve the system of equations all equal to $0$, all the coefficients are $0$.

> c) The set $B$ is a basis for $W$. Write down $[g]_B$.

Is this not just: $[g]_B = \frac{1}{2}[f_1]_B - [f_2]_B +\frac{1}{2}[f_3]_B$? This seems very trivial.

If someone could verify my work and check this over, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** OK.

**b)** I think that you should at least elaborate of which coefficients you're speaking, same for your system of equations and why those coefficients are equal to zero.

**c)** You should state that as $W=\text{Span}\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$, $\dim W$ is at most equal to $3$. Now as $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors that also spans $W$, it is a basis of $W$. And as all basis have the same cardinal, $\dim W=3$. *I know that this is a bit verbose, but as you seem to be following a linear algebra course, better to mention precisely what you're learning!*.

Comment: Ohh for part c, I don't need to do that as I am told in part b that $f_1,f_2,f_3$ forms a basis in part b, otherwise I absolutely agree with you.

Is this method correct for part c?

Comment: If I read correctly, in part b) you're asked to prove that the vectors are linearly independent. It is in part c) that you have to conclude that they form a basis. No?

Comment: No. I don't need to. It says in part c, "The set $B$ is a basis for $W$". For part c, is it just asking for the coordinates?